# How can I distinguish internal from external updates in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using iOS/Swift with [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) as my backend.

When the value of a reference change, I get notified, because I'm adding an observer.

What I need is to be able to know when this change was triggered from my local code or from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a child to your reference which stores the uid of the user that updated the reference and compare it with the current app user

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that's not very practical. Let's say user1 updates "/node/p1": true, and user2 updates "/node/p2": false. Now I need "/node/p1": { value: true, updatedBy: user1ID} and "/node/p2": { value: false, updatedBy: user2ID }. And what if user3 now updates "/node/p2/x": true? Now I need the updatedBy field in every level of the tree.